# use angular service vs export class for multiple instances?

Tags: angular, service

I'm having trouble understanding how to handle multiple instances of a service in Angular. In the example below, I want to create multiple instances of the type Person. Since Person is not a singleton, I don't inject it. Would it make more sense to simply import it as a Person class and skip doing it the Angular way?

person.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class Person {
  constructor(private name: string) { }
  talk() {
    console.log(`${this.name} is talking!`)
  }
```

}

app.component.ts

```
 export class AppComponent {
 ngOnInit() {
   let a = ['Bob','Amy','Joe']
   let instances = a.map(rec=> new Person(rec))
   instances.forEach(person=> person.talk())
 }
```

}

Output:
Bob is talking!
Amy is talking!
Joe is talking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that Angular injector propagates singleton pattern with default provider type (`useClass`) is only one of benefits that DI provides.

It's possible to avoid singletons if they aren't desirable and still use DI, at least for testing reasons:

```
providers: [{ provide: Person, useValue: Person }]
```

and

```
export class AppComponent {
 constructor(@Inject(Person) private Person: typeof Person) {}
 ngOnInit() {
   ...
   let instances = a.map(rec=> new this.Person(rec))
   ...
 }
```

Otherwise a class cannot be mocked entirely in tests via `TestBed`. Currently `Person` constructor doesn't contain the code that would make it necessary to be mocked.

Answer (score 0):

In the example given, Person is a type -- not really a service.

If the Person type is a simple type, say just a Plain Old JavaScript Object -- I would just `new` it up. A good example of this would be `Ngrx` actions. These are just simply types that do not need to be mocked for testing -- and can safely be newed up.

If this is more complex and you should mock it out for testing, use @estus answer.